# Does alfresco supports append-only relations?

Tags: java, alfresco

Suppos a model contains association:

```
            <association name="sc:presons">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <many>true</many>
                </target>
            </association>
```

ALfresco share support "mark" this field as readonly. But can it mark it as `append-only`? E.g. adding new presons is ok, but removing is forbidden?

Comment: Try to use http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/node/NodeServicePolicies.BeforeDeleteChildAssociationPolicy.html

Comment: It's a presentation requirement, so you need to create your own custom form control